# Wrong Plot of line chart(stock graph) using D3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg, charts

I am trying to plot a line chart using D3.js. The  problem is that for some stock symbols the graph is correct and for some it gives a wrong chart.
I have attached two images. One showing a line chart that shows the wrong graph for a particular stock.The other one shows the correct graph for an another stock.
Look the d attribute of the path tag in the svg (in the images that I hace attached).The values of the d attribute are way off the charts for the wrong graph.The two graphs that I have shown are generated from the same program.

[Wrong Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ0eo.png)
[Correct Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxf4I.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your scale is off. If you look at the axis on your wrong chart the numbers are in a tight range, apparently outside of the highs and lows. Check the code where you define the domain for the y scale.